# How can an experieced programmer get into embedded programming and robotics

Tags: embedded, programming, robotics, uav

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to become an embedded software developer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/how-to-become-an-embedded-software-developer)

I would like to know what is the best method to begin learning embedded programming and electronic skills? I am already very good at programming and am an MIS grad. My goal is to begin designing and creating my own robots and UAV's from scratch (without any kits of any sort).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to become an embedded software developer?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/how-to-become-an-embedded-software-developer) , [how-to-start-embedded-programming?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32800/how-to-start-embedded-programming?rq=1) , [first-step-in-embedded-system?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29340/first-step-in-embedded-system?rq=1)

Comment: Start by proof-reading your posts. An "experienced" programmer shouldn't make obvious spelling errors in the title of their posts.

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents: If you want to build a robot, take a subset of the problem and learn everything you need to know to accomplish that. If you want to build a wheeled robot, maybe first try to control a motor to drive forwards and backwards using an Arduino. If you can do that (e.g. with an H-bridge), you can basically already build a simple car. Then keep incrementally building functionality (step two, get an IR receiver and use a TV remote to control your car). Maybe next you could create IR beacons for your robot to track, etc. I think this sort of way you can immediately apply the knowledge you want as you need it.